# login through facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Now I am working on login through facebook. For that I am using android sdk 3.0. In  my app I have to get users email id. I am using the following code to get the email id but I am unable to to get. can u give me any suggestion w I am doing wrong. Everytime I am going to else part.

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    // for error on login
    loginButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);

    // set permission list, Don't forget to add email
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));

    // session state call back event

    loginButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());
                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            "Email "
                                                    + user.asMap().get(
                                                            "email"));

                                }
                            }

                        });

            } else {
                Log.d("session is not valid", ""
                        + Session.getActiveSession().getState());
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Post the log of "session is not valid"

Comment: At first I got the CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED.I got the Error remote_app_id does not match stored id.Here the app id and keygeneration did by my colleague. Shared the code to me. When I try to login with facebook I got this error.

Comment: well this is due to a wrong key, , u have to get a new key, try a keytool make sure you have the java specific keytool ie. keytool that comes with  1.6 or 1.7

Comment: Actually he is using 1.7 and I am using 1.6.

Comment: Then thats the problem,To resolve it make ur key with keytool that comes with 1.6

Comment: What is the problem with that, we are using different systems and all are working on same application. how can each one get same key? One can create the app with package name and class name. we have to share that code and to work on that. What is the solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get you key

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "Your Pakage name", 
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
```

the key will be displayed in the log.

Another thing (Based on your comment) is that you should try an SVN so that your team can work on the same project without any conflicts

Comment: I know that. We are using SVN. But through svn we are sharing the code. But Why I got that error. The process is correct or not.When i get the email I have to sent a server call using that emailid. And I am asking for What I am using methods are correct or not?